# How to simplify the following if statements and ternary operators?

Tags: javascript

The following code is inside a loop which loops through the fields of a form. If `isV1User` is `true`, then the field is disabled. If the user has `customSetting` then don't disable the field. If the user doesn't have it, disable it.

```
if (field.name === 'themeColor') {
  if (this.isV1User) {
    field.disabled = false
  } else {
    field.disabled = this.user.customSetting
      ? !this.user.customSetting.themePicker
      : false
  }
}
```

How to simplify or at least remove the nesting of this code?

Comment: Why? (he wanted to simply ask, but StackOverflow demanded more characters.)

Comment: _"If isV1User is true, then the field is disabled. If the user has customSetting then don't disable the field. If the user doesn't have it, disable it."_ - so, simply put, disable it if the user isV1User _or_ the user does not have a custom setting ...?

Comment: You should post your question to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move every `if` condition to ternary:

```
if (field.name === 'themeColor') {
    field.disabled = !this.isV1User && this.user.customSetting && !this.user.customSetting.themePicker;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (field.name === 'themeColor') {
    field.disabled = this.user.customSetting && !this.isV1User ?
    !this.user.customSetting.themePicker : false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a Stack Overflow question, would fit better on Code Review I guess.

There's only one set of circumstances in which it needs to be `true`, it seems, so maybe like this?

```
if (field.name === 'themeColor') {
    field.disabled = (
        !this.isV1User &&
        this.user.customSetting && !this.user.customSetting.themePicker);
}
```

The first `if` is still needed because other fields should remain unchanged (I assume).

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
    "themeColor"===field.name && (field.disabled=this.isV1User?!1:
this.user.customSetting?!this.user.customSetting.themePicker:!1);
```

Comment: If field name is not `themeColor`, you still change field `disabled` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

The way that you have structured your code, it can be minimized to the following equivalent code. Please note that if `this.user.customSetting.themePicker` is guaranteed to always be true when `this.user.customSetting` is true, you can set `field.disabled = true` in a single if statement where the conditional is `field.name == 'themeColor'`:

```
if (field.name == 'themeColor' && this.user.customSetting) {
 field.disabled = !this.user.customSetting.themePicker;
} else if (field.name == 'themeColor') {
 field.disabled = false;
}
```

Or even the following switch statement, depending on how you want your code structured. They both are the same.

```
switch (field.name) {
  case 'themeColor':
    if (this.user.customSetting) {
      field.disabled = !this.user.customSetting.themePicker;
    }
    break;
  default:
    field.disabled = false;
}
```

Most of these answers break the cardinal rule of ternary statement readability. If your goal is simplistic readability, breaking it down to a simple `if/else if` statement will do. If you are trying to minimize the code as much as possible, and don't care if it's unmaintainable/hard to read, you should simplify it to a recursive ternary statement. Personally, I find that long ternary statements do not provide significant space-saving, hamper readability, and should be avoided in cases where they are not extremely simple (ie: `var x = statement? 1 : 0;`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (field.name === 'themeColor') {
   field.disabled = this.isV1User ? true : this.user.customSetting ? !this.user.customSetting.themePicker : false;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your code is working? Ternary operator is working right-to-left, also as *pro-tip* multiple ternary operators without any `()` is **very** confusing and hard to read.